# Write a code to generate a new .sas file from a sas code

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I need help please help me, I want write a code to generate a new .sas file from a sas code and a new file at a particular location.

Thanks in advance

I have Extract excel sheet name in sas and want to continue with generate new .sas file from this code

```
/**Assign a libname for excel sheet*/
libname inexcel xlsx '/home/viadmin/casuser/mapping.xlsx';

PROC CONTENTS DATA=inexcel._ALL_ noprint
OUT=Sheets (KEEP=Memname);
RUN;

PROC SORT DATA=Sheets NODUPLICATES;
BY Memname;
RUN;

DATA Sheets;
SET Sheets;
ID=_N_;
RUN;

DATA _NULL_;
IF 0 THEN SET Sheets NOBS=X;
CALL SYMPUT('Recount', X);
STOP;
RUN;


%macro Excel;
%DO i = 1 %TO &Recount;
PROC SQL ;
create table sheet&i. as
SELECT Memname INTO :Name
FROM Sheets WHERE ID = &i;
quit;
%end;
%mend;

%excel;
```

Till here code is working fine.
But after this i want to genearte new .sas file for different Names
like- sheet1.sas, sheet2.sas

Comment: If you want to make a copy of a .sas file, the easiest way is to use your operating systems, COPY command.  If you have options XCMD enabled, you could call this command from SAS. But often having multiple programs (one per sheet) to maintain becomes a difficult mess. Since you already have one macro in your program, did you consider developing a macro that would process each sheet, rather than creating a separate .sas program for each sheet?

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting in your *sheet1.sas* file ?

Do you want output data sets whose names match the worksheet names ?

Consider using the `XLSX` library engine and `Proc COPY`.

```
libname mybook xlxs 'mapping.xlsx';

proc copy in=mybook out=work;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

See my GitHub page with how to generate SAS code from SAS: https://github.com/savian-net/SasTipsTricks#dynamic-code